# С каждым нажатием кнопки "buy", появляется всё больше кнопок

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Делаю интернет-магазин. При нажатии на кнопку "купить", у товара пропадает кнопка "купить" и появляется либо -1, либо +1, т.е больше у этого товара нет кнопки купить, можно только увеличить количество, так и нужно.
Суть проблемы: при первом нажатии на любой товар - всё работает корректно. Но если нажать на другом товаре "купить", то у первого товара появляется снова кнопка купить, но теперь их даже две и с каждым нажатием купить - кнопок "купить" появляется больше.
[image: To view img]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <section id="header">
        <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" alt=""></a>

        <div>
            <ul id="navbar">
                <li><a class="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li id="lg-bag"><a href="cart.html"><i class="far fa-shopping-bag"></i></a></li><div id="score"></div>
                <a href="#" id="close"><i class="far fa-times"></i></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="mobile">
            <a href="cart.html"><i class="far fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>
            <i id="bar" class="fas fa-outdent"></i>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="hero">
        <div id="mini-cart"></div>
        <h4>Trade-in-offer</h4>
        <h2>Super value deals</h2>
        <h1>On all products</h1>
        <p>Save more with coupons & up to 70% off!</p>
        <button>Shop Now</button>
    </section>
    <section id="feature" class="section-p1">
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f1.png" alt="">
            <h6>Free Shipping</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f2.png" alt="">
            <h6>Online Order</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f3.png" alt="">
            <h6>Save money</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f4.png" alt="">
            <h6>Promotions</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f5.png" alt="">
            <h6>Happy Sell</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="fe-box">
            <img src="img/features/f6.png" alt="">
            <h6>24/7 Support</h6>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
        <h2>Featured products</h2>
        <p>Summer Collection New Morden Design</p>
        <div class="pro-container" id="goods">
            
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <section id="banner" class="section-m1">
        <h4>Reapir Services</h4>
        <h2>Up to <span>70% Off</span> - All t-Shirts & Accessories</h2>
        <button class="normal">Explore More</button>
    </section>

    <section id="product1" class="section-p1">
        <h2>New Arrivals</h2>
        <p>Summer Collection New Morden Design</p>
        <div class="pro-container">
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n1.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n2.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n3.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n4.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n5.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n6.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n7.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="pro">
                <img src="img/products/n8.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="des">
                    <span>Adidas</span>
                    <h5>Cartoon Astronaut T-Shirt</h5>
                    <div class="star">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <h4>$78</h4>
                </div>
                <a href="#"><i class="fal fa-shopping-cart cart"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="sm-banner" class="section-p1">
        <div class="banner-box">
            <h4>crazy deals</h4>
            <h2>buy 1 get 1 free</h2>
            <span>The best classic dress is on sale at cara</span>
            <button class="white">Learn More</button>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-box banner-box2">
            <h4>spring/summer</h4>
            <h2>upcomming season</h2>
            <span>The best classic dress is on sale at cara</span>
            <button class="white">Collection</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="banner3">
        <div class="banner-box">
            <h2>SEASONAL SALE</h2>
            <h3>Winter Collection -50% OFF</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-box banner-box2">
            <h2>NEW FOOTWEAR COLLECTION</h2>
            <h3>Spring / Summer 2022</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="banner-box banner-box3">
            <h2>T-SHIRTS</h2>
            <h3>New Trendy Prints</h3>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="newsletter" class="section-p1 section-m1">
        <div class="newstext">
            <h4>Sign Up For Newsletter</h4>
            <p>Get E-mail updates about our latest shop and <span>special offers.</span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your email address">
            <button class="normal">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer class="section-p1">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="logo">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <p><strong>Address:</strong> 562 Wellington Road, Street 32, San Francisco</p>
            <p><strong>Phone:</strong> +01 2222 365 /(+91) 01 2345 6789</p>
            <p><strong>Hours:</strong> 10:00 - 18:00, Mon - Sat</p>
            <div class="follow">
                <h4>Follow us</h4>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i>
                    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <h4>About</h4>
            <a href="#">About us</a>
            <a href="#">Delivery Information</a>
            <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="#">Terms & Conditions</a>
            <a href="#">Contact us</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <h4>My Account</h4>
            <a href="#">Sign up</a>
            <a href="#">View Cart</a>
            <a href="#">My Wishlist</a>
            <a href="#">Track My Order</a>
            <a href="#">Help</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col install">
            <h4>Install App</h4>
            <p>From App Store or Google Play</p>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="img/pay/app.jpg" alt="">
                <img src="img/pay/play.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
            <p>Secured Payment Gateways</p>
            <img src="img/pay/pay.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>(c) 2022, Tech2 etc - HTML CSS Ecommerce Template</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
var cart = {}; //Моя корзина
var button = {}

$('document').ready(function() {
    loadGoods();
    checkCart();
    showButton();
    scorer();

});

const bar = document.getElementById('bar');
const close = document.getElementById('close');
const nav = document.getElementById('navbar');

if (bar) {
    bar.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.add('active');
    })
}

if (close) {
    close.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.remove('active');
    })
};


//Выгружаем товары на страницу
function loadGoods() {

    $.getJSON('goods.json', function (data) {
        var out = '';
        if($.isEmptyObject(cart)) {
            for (var key in data) {
                out+= '<div class="pro">';
                out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'" alt="">';
                out+='<div class="des">';
                out+='<span>Adidas</span>';
                out+='<h5>Cartoon Astronaut '+data[key]['name']+'</h5>';
                out+='<div class="star">';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='</div>';
                out+='<h4>$'+data[key]['cost']+'</h4>';
                out+='</div>';
                out+='<button class="normal add" data-art="'+key+'" id="fire">Buy</button>';
                out+='</div>';
            }

        } else {
            for (var key in data) {
                out+= '<div class="pro">';
                out+='<img src="'+data[key].image+'" alt="">';
                out+='<div class="des">';
                out+='<span>Adidas</span>';
                out+='<h5>Cartoon Astronaut '+data[key]['name']+'</h5>';
                out+='<div class="star">';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='<i class="fas fa-star"></i>';
                out+='</div>';
                out+='<h4>$'+data[key]['cost']+'</h4>';
                out+='</div>';
                    for (var w in cart) {
                        if (w == key) {
                        out+='<button class="minus">-1</button>';                     
                        out+='<p>В корзине:</p>';
                        out+='<button class="plus" >+1</button>';
                    } else {
                        out+='<button class="normal add" data-art="'+key+'" id="fire">Buy</button>'; 
                    } 
                }

                out+='</div>';
    }
        }

        $('#goods').html(out);
        $('button.add').on('click', addToCart);
    });
}

//Выводим кол-во элементов в массиве cart
function scorer() {

    score = Object.keys(cart).length;
    $('#score').html(score);
}

function checkCartItems(){
    $('.cart td.name p').each(function(){
        var itemName = $(this).text();
        $('[data-name="'+itemName+'"]').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
    });
}
checkCartItems();


//Добавляем товар в корзину
function addToCart() {
    var article = $(this).attr('data-art');
    if (cart[article] != undefined) {
        cart[article]++;
    } else {
        cart[article] = 1;   
    }

    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));


    localStorage.setItem('button', JSON.stringify(button));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    //console.log(cart);
    scorer();
    loadGoods();
}


//Проверяем наличие корзины в localStorage
function checkCart() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('cart') != null) {
        cart = JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem('cart'))
    };
}
```

Comment: прикрепите полный код. html тоже

Comment: Спасибо. Добавил html. CSS не даёт добавить, слишком много строк